# Download HTTPS website available only through username and password with wget?

Tags: wget, https

I'm trying to recursively download website which is normally available only when you login.

I have valid username and password, but the problem is that I need to login through web interface, so using `--user=user and --password=password` doesn't help.

`wget` downloads only one webpage with text:
*Sorry this page is not available, maybe you've forgotten to login?*

Is it possible to download?

I can't use --user, --password even at the login page because there is no FTP/HTTP file retrieval login as mentioned in `man wget`:

```
--user=user
--password=password
    Specify the username user and password password for both FTP and
    HTTP file retrieval.
```

Classic graphical login is there.

If I try to do this: `wget --save-cookies coookies --keep-session-cookies --post-data='j_username=usr&j_password=pwd' 'https://idp2.civ.cvut.cz/idp/Authn/UserPassword'`. Using POST method to login and trying to save cookies, the coookies file is empty and the saved page is some error page.

**The URL is `https://idp2.civ.cvut.cz/idp/Authn/UserPassword`. Actually, when I want to log in, it redirects me to this page and when I successfully log in, it redirects me back to the page where I was before or some page where I wanted to be after logging in (example: `https://progtest.fit.cvut.cz/`.**

Comment: When you login, a cookie is probably set by the website. Use the cookie functionality of `wget` to indicate to the server that you are logged in and you are set! ;)

Comment: @Mike : Does my provided answer help? Perhaps if you could provide the exact https url, then we could work out the solution for it.

Comment: @shivams I have updated my question.

Comment: You say you are redirected to login and then go back to the page you were before. In that case, the page you come from might also add some info needed for authentication. Could you give us an example of a page that redirects you to the login page?

Comment: @user43791 Updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The session information is probably saved in a cookie to allow you to navigate to other pages after you have logged in.

If this is the case, you could do this in two steps :

1. Use `wget`'s `--save-cookies mycookies.txt` and `--keep-session-cookies` options on the login page of the website along with your `--username` and `--password` options
2. Use `wget`'s `--load-cookies mycookies.txt` option on the subsequent pages you are trying to retrieve.

**EDIT**

If the `--password` and `--username` option doesn't work, you must find out the info sent to the server by the login page and mimic it :

- For a `GET` request, you can add the `GET` parameters directly in the address wget must fetch (make sure you properly quote the `&`, `=` and other special characters). The url would probably look something like `https://the_url?user=foo&pass=bar`.
- For a `POST` request you can use `wget`'s `--post-data=the_needed_info` option to use the post method on the needed login info.

**EDIT 2**

It seems that you indeed need the `POST` method with the `j_username` and `j_password` set. Try `--post-data='j_username=yourusername&j_password=yourpassword` option to `wget`.

**EDIT 3**

With the page of origin, I was able to understand a little more of what is happening. That being said, I cannot make sure that it works because, well, I don't have (nor do I want) valid credentials.

That being said, here is what's happening :

1. The page `https://progtest.fit.cvut.cz/` sets a `PHPSESSID` cookie and present you with login options.
2. Clicking the `login` button sends a request to `https://progtest.fit.cvut.cz/shibboleth-fit.php` which takes the PHPSESSID cookie (not sure if it uses it) and redirects you to the SSO engine with a specially crafted url just for you which looks like this : `https://idp2.civ.cvut.cz/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?SAMLRequest=SOME_VERY_LONG_AND_UNIQUE_ID`
3. The SSO response sets a new cookie named `_idp_authn_lc_key` and redirects you to the page `https://idp2.civ.cvut.cz:443/idp/AuthnEngine` which redirects you again to `https://idp2.civ.cvut.cz:443/idp/Authn/UserPassword` (the real login page)
4. You enter your credentials and send the post data `j_username` and `j_password` along with the cookie from the SSO response
5. ???

The first four steps can be done with `wget` like this :

```
origin='https://progtest.fit.cvut.cz/'

# Get the PHPSESSID cookie
wget --save-cookies phpsid.cki --keep-session-cookies "$origin"

# Get the _idp_authn_lc_key cookie
wget --load-cookies phpsid.cki  --save-cookies sso.cki --keep-session-cookies --header="Referer: $origin" 'https://progtest.fit.cvut.cz/shibboleth-fit.php'

# Send your credentials
wget --load-cookies sso.cki --save-cookies auth.cki --keep-session-cookies --post-data='j_username=usr&j_password=pwd' 'https://idp2.civ.cvut.cz/idp/Authn/UserPassword'
```

Note that `wget` follows redirection all by himself, which helps us quite a bit in this case.

Comment: I can't login with --user --password even at the login page...

Comment: @Mike The website doesn't use standard HTTP login, then. What kind of login page is it? How does it send the login info? Using a `POST` request? Using a `GET` request? The login page must send something to the server. Find out what and how and mimic that with `wget`! ;)

Comment: It's this page: https://idp2.civ.cvut.cz/idp/Authn/UserPassword. It sends login info using `POST` method. But I don't know how to mimic that with wget.

Comment: @Mike I've edited my answer to reflect that new fact.

Comment: Is this right? 
`wget --save-cookies coookies --keep-session-cookies --post-data='j_username=usr&j_password=pwd' 'https://idp2.civ.cvut.cz/idp/Authn/UserPassword'`
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, it doesn't save any cookies and the saved html page is some error page.
(It saves coookies file with some header but with no cookies below.)

Comment: @Mike When you try opening the saved page in a browser, what error does it indicates?

Comment: This one: http://postimg.org/image/ty0iw64ej/

I have also updated my question.

Comment: @Mike can't look at the picture right now (blocked) but I updated my answer based on your most recent information.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you playing around with `wget`? Better use some [headless browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) to automate this task.

What is a headless browser, you ask?

> A headless browser is a web browser without a graphical user interface.
>   They provide automated control of a web page in an environment similar to popular web browsers, but are executed via a command line interface or using network communication.

Two popular headless browsers are `phantomjs` (javascript) and `Ghost.py` (python).

#### Solution using phantomjs

First you will need to install `phantomjs`. On Ubuntu based systems, you can install it using the package manager or you could build it from source from their [home page](http://phantomjs.org/download.html).

```
sudo apt-get install phantomjs
```

After this you write javascript script and run it using phantomjs:

```
phantomjs script.js
```

That's it.

Now, to learn how to implement it for your case, head over to its [quickstart guide](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html). As an example, to login to facebook automatically, and take a snapshot, one could use the gist provided [here](https://github.com/manishjo/Automation/blob/master/facebook_automation/fbScreenshot.js):

```js
// This code login's to your facebook account and takes snap shot of it.
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fillLoginInfo = function(){
var frm = document.getElementById("login_form");
frm.elements["email"].value = 'your fb email/username';
frm.elements["pass"].value = 'password';
frm.submit();
}
page.onLoadFinished = function(){
if(page.title == "Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More"){
page.evaluate(fillLoginInfo);
return;
}
else
page.render('./screens/some.png');
console.log("completed");
phantom.exit();
}
page.open('https://www.facebook.com/');
```

Look around the documentation to implement it for your specific case. If you face some troubles for your `https` website due to ssl errors, run your script like this:

```
phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any script.js
```

#### Solution using Ghost.py

To install Ghost.py, you will need `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip   #On a Debian based system
sudo pip install Ghost.py
```

Now you have installed Ghost.py. Now, to use it inside a python script, just follow the documentation given in its [home page](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/). I've tried using Ghost.py on an https website but it somehow didn't work for me. Do try it and see if it works.

### UPDATE : GUI based solution

You can also use tools like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to automate the login process and retrieve the information. It is pretty easy to use. You will just need to install a plugin for your browser from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/). And then you can record your process and replay it later on.

Comment: Looking for such a thing for a long time. Does it support text field summition ?

Comment: Yes. Of course. Both of them do. You can fill forms with any kind of fields and submit 'em. Just go to their documentation and read it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `'curl'`

```
curl --data "j_username=value1&j_password=value2" https://idp2.civ.cvut.cz/idp/Authn/UserPassword
```

You may need to look at the response type and set the `'content-type'` header to match; i.e: XML, json etc

Comment: I've done this kind of thing with curl before with great success. +1

Answer (score 0):

In addion to cookies, use *user agent* as firefox, chrome etc. Because most servers hate dwonload managers.

**Alternatively**  use firefox extension **scrap book**

- easy to use
- GUI

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is: First I would use live HTTP Headers pluggin for firefox to analyze the communication. Referers and all that stuff may be needed. Once I have that information I would mimic that with `wget` saving cookies and loading when needed.

Answer (score 0):

For a more modern tool to perform these kind of operations, checkout `HTTPie`:

https://httpie.org/

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and finally wrote a tool based on **user43791**'s answer.

Therefore, what you are looking for is maybe something like that:
https://github.com/atar-axis/TUM-tools/blob/master/moodle_grabber/moodle_grabber.sh

It should be very easy to adapt this to any other shibboleth site and it is based only on wget!