# wget gives me html file instead of the target file

Tags: linux, wget, html

I'm using wget to download files but seemingly it gives HTML file instead of the file that I need.

my wget version is GNU Wget 1.19.1 built on linux-gnu and here's the command line I used:

```bash
wget --user=... --password=... https://transfer.usz.ch/messages/O6Xk6MAxMUYYIql5OTSRlo/attachments/dgzQv5Nl8Sv1eS6GDdtY3S/download/B201643229_T_S60_sort_merge_dup_recal_RGtag.bam
```

I wonder what made this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the site you linked, it seems that you expect wget to pass your supplied username and password to the form on the website; wget does not support this.

The `--user` and `--password` arguments are intended to be used for FTP or HTTP basic authentication, as stated in wget’s manual.

See this question for more information on how to accomplish what you are trying to do: [Download HTTPS website available only through username and password with wget?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205135/download-https-website-available-only-through-username-and-password-with-wget)